# File Upload replication between cluster in JBOSS

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

I have a web application running on JBoss and we have successfully setup a cluster.
In our web application  we allow user to upload an image file which get stored at in a system folder now my question is that how to get those files replicated across cluster.
Is there any way out to replicate that file stored in the other node of the cluster using Jboss.
Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

In Jboss 5.1, there is a folder "farm" in JBoss's "all" profile. Everything in this folder will be synchroinzed in a cluster.

Do you really want to replicate user uploaded files in a cluster?

Comment: Farming is not very reliable in JBoss5. It has a number of issues/bugs and generally not recommended to be utilized in production.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be (and *shouldn't be*) done over clustering. If you want files to be replicated then you should utilize a shared file system like NFS or other persisted storage options like a database server (would be a more costly alternative to NFS though).